# Delete confirm dialog not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, confirm-dialog

I defined a link_to in the user profile page to delete the account.

```
= link_to "Delete My Account", user_path(@user), :method=>:delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to delete your account?"
```

The Jquery code was in javascripts/application.js as follows:

```
var delete_path = $(this).attr('href');

$(".confirm").confirm({
text: "Are you sure you want to delete your account?",
title: "Confirmation required",

confirm: function(button) {
    alert("You have confirm!")
    window.location.href = delete_path;
},
cancel: function(button) {
     $(this).dialog("close");
},
confirmButton: "Yes I want to delete my account",
cancelButton: "No I want to go back",
post: true,
confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg" // Bootstrap classes for large modal});
```

Actually the button function well and the account was deleted successfully. But the confirm dialog didn't show up. I am new to Jquery. Don't know if some components are missed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your delete link from

```
= link_to "Delete My Account", user_path(@user), :method=>:delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to delete your account?"
```

to

```
= link_to "Delete My Account", user_path(@user), :method=>:delete, data: {:confirm => "Are you sure to delete your account?"}
```

it will show confirm dialog box before deleting record.